# How to combine "AND" and "OR" queries to get results of both?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use one query to get the results of two queries.

I have to run two queries for each multi-word string query request, and then combine the results programmatically in the code which doesn't feel right to me.

One of the queries uses the `AND` operator, one of them uses the `OR` operator.

Here is the first query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {"exists": {"field": "deleted"}}
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "refuse eating",
            "fields": [
              "title^3",
              "desc^2",
              "body"
            ],
            "type": "best_fields",
            "operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {"term": {"kind": "article"}},
        {"term": {"status": "published"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the second query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {"exists": {"field": "deleted"}}
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "refuse eating",
            "fields": [
              "title^3",
              "desc^2",
              "body"
            ],
            "type": "best_fields",
            "operator": "OR"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {"term": {"kind": "article"}},
        {"term": {"status": "published"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is to get the results of the first query (the query that uses `AND` operator) at the **top**, then get the results of the second query (the query that uses `OR` operator) *below* the first results.

Is there any way to achieve that with a **single** query instead of two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably leverage `bool/should` with a higher `boost` factor for AND matches:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "deleted"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "refuse eating",
            "fields": [
              "title^3",
              "desc^2",
              "body"
            ],
            "type": "best_fields",
            "operator": "AND",
            "boost": 2,                   <--- boost AND by 2 (or more)
            "_name": "and-match"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "refuse eating",
            "fields": [
              "title^3",
              "desc^2",
              "body"
            ],
            "type": "best_fields",
            "operator": "OR",
            "_name": "or-match"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "kind": "article"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "published"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works for me for now. Appreciated :)